# Firebase messaging token is returning null in SUNMI V2 device

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i wrote flutter app and i have tested on all versions of android devices and its working fine but when i send apk to client Firebase cloud messaging token returns null.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nabeel Ahmad I am facing same problem, Sunmi V2 devide doesn't generate token when apk is replaced and I have to clean data many times to generate token, let me know if you find any solution!!

Comment: it was a device issue. my client bought new device sunmi v2 pro and app is working fine

Comment: dis you find the solution or any information about this problem

Comment: yes @AhmetAydemir it was a google play services issue either its disabled in your device or update it to latest version

Comment: my device doesnt have google play. what should I do?

Comment: install it. its necessary in order to run firebase services you can check their documentation